# Is there a log that shows the exact commands taken to get the server to the current state?

Tags: server

Our hosting company has setup a "hardened template" of Ubuntu Server 12.04 to be used as a web server. Which I have interpreted as a base install with a bunch of additional tweaks including firewall settings and installing the basics like SSH/PHP/mySQL.

Is there a way to view/download the exact commands/tweaks done to get the server to it's current state. I am asking this, so if I do "stuff up" anything I can revert to a fresh "hardened template" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are two things you could do. Option A (easier) would be to just make an image of the drive when you first get it and restore from that whenever needed. Option B (harder) would be to diff every file against their originals. "Every file" should be read as the output of `dpkg -l` and likely everything under `/var` and `/etc`.

The only record of what is done to a machine would be what is in your shell history (which they likely didn't leave around for you) and in the logs of utilities like `dpkg` and `apt` which can likely be regenerated easier by using `dpkg -l` than by parsing the logs.

Side note: I guess option C would be to ask your provider what they did.

Comment: Option C is yes an option :) In terms of Option A, is there a quick link to making an image, if not I will starting researching

Comment: I guess that depends on the type of image you want to do. The easiest solution would be to use `dd`, which will make a byte-for-byte copy of the partition (that includes non-used space). With compression you'll use something like `dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /mnt/backup/sda.img.gz`

Comment: The downsides being that it is slow and the output before compression is large. Another option would be to use a tool like `rsync` however I'm not really certain how well it deals with hardlinks and symlinks so I don't generally use it for OS files.